# Inventory Adjustment script with GL impact

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to create an Inventory Adjustment user-event script. though, I am unable to do the GL impact that happens after the record gets created. To trigger the GL impact, I am setting the Estimated Total Value field by script, but I get an error saying "Transaction is not balanced". But when I do it manually same amount is getting set in estimated total value which I am setting by script

```
function create_inv_adjustment(fromlocation,adjAccount,objRecord,nRecType)
{
    log.debug('create_inv_adjustment','entry');
    var count = objRecord.getLineCount('custpage_itemsublist');
    log.debug('create_inv_adjustment','lineCount : '+count);
    var new_inv_adjustment = record.create({ type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ADJUSTMENT, isDynamic: true })

        new_inv_adjustment.setValue({ fieldId:'account', value: adjAccount })
        new_inv_adjustment.setValue({ fieldId:'adjlocation', value: fromlocation })

    if(count > 0)
    {
        var estimatedtotalvalue = 0;
        for(i=0; i<count; i++)
        {
            var item = objRecord.getSublistValue({
                sublistId : 'custpage_itemsublist',
                fieldId : 'custpage_item',
                line : i                                        });

            log.debug('create_inv_adjustment','itemName : '+item);

                var quantity = objRecord.getSublistValue({
                    sublistId : 'custpage_itemsublist',
                    fieldId : 'custpage_quantity',
                    line : i                                    });
                log.debug('create_inv_adjustment','itemquantity : '+quantity);
            var description = objRecord.getSublistValue({
                sublistId : 'custpage_itemsublist',
                fieldId : 'custpage_description',
                line : i                                        });

            if(quantity == '' || quantity == null)
            {}
            else
            {
                new_inv_adjustment.selectNewLine({
                    sublistId: 'inventory'
                });
                new_inv_adjustment.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'inventory',
                            fieldId: 'item',
                            value: item     ,ignoreFieldChange:true             });
                new_inv_adjustment.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'inventory',
                            fieldId: 'adjustqtyby',
                            value: quantity     ,ignoreFieldChange:true         });
                new_inv_adjustment.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'inventory',
                            fieldId: 'description',
                            value: chkNull(description) ,ignoreFieldChange:true });
                new_inv_adjustment.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'inventory',
                            fieldId: 'location',
                            value: chkNull(fromlocation),ignoreFieldChange:true     });
                new_inv_adjustment.commitLine({
                    sublistId: 'inventory'
                });
            }
        }
    }
    var save = new_inv_adjustment.save({    
        enableSourcing: true,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: true
    });
    log.debug('create_inv_adjustment','inv-adj saved : '+save);
}
```

Currently, only the inv-adjustment is getting without GL impact. Can I use suiteGL instead?

Comment: Adjusting quantity down the value should come from the current cost for the inventory. Only when increasing inventory would you supply your own value or let it use the current cost by default (the usual setting).

Comment: @Brian Do I have to enable some setting for this?

Comment: Can you share the whole script you have starting from the record.create all the way to record.save?

Comment: @vVinceth I have added whole script. please have a look. I am createing the inv-adjustment rec from a custom record

Answer (score 0):

While creating inventory adjustment by script, set the unitcost field in linelevel which will do the GL impact after creation of that record.